# Broken links in answers

Tags: discussion

Do we have a policy on broken links?

I came across an [answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/3214/7502) that had a broken link.  In this case the answer was little more than the link in question. I think the policy might depend on whether the answer includes non-link content.

I managed to find an archive.org copy of the original, and I edited the question with the updated link.  Should I have just flagged it instead?

Answer (score 4):

In general, when you find a broken link, edit the post to contain a working version of the link, if you can find one. If not, just remove the link altogether. Since anyone can suggest or submit edits, there's no need to flag just for this.

If the post should be flagged for another reason, then sure, go ahead and flag it for that reason. But that's a separate, independent issue from fixing broken links.

Answer (score 2):

Answers that contain no information directly on the page, even if they have a link to information, should be flagged as "Not an Answer". Alternatively, you can edit the answer to include the information from the link. But answers should answer the question, with external reference material as supplementary.